# Class constructor statement

Tags: python, constructor

I've been looking at the following code and have a question about what it means. The package overall has the classes: Segment, Cell, Column, Region, and SegmentUpdateInfo. 
The code in question is the last line. Thanks in advance!

```
class SegmentUpdateInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, cell, segment, activeSynapses, addNewSynapses=False):
        #Constructor parameter initialization...

        region = self.cell.column.region #What does this mean and why would someone use 
                                         #it?
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the meaning of that line can only be found in the other parts of the code that you haven't posted. Some code you omitted sets `self.cell` to some value (probably the `cell` argument to the constructor), then accesses its `column` member in the line you're asking about (and accesses the `region` member of that). I don't know what any of those values are, so I can't explain the meaning.

Comment: I'll give good odds this is simply an abbreviation.  That line simply makes a new name, `region`, for the `self.cell.column.region` object.  Since the name is local to the `__init__` method, probably it's just done to save keystrokes for some lines later in `__init__` which would otherwise need to spell out `self.cell.column.region`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason someone would do that is so that they can refer to that variable within `__init__()` without typing `self.cell.column.region` every single time. Is there anywhere else in the `__init__()` method that `region` is used?